# Set alias to run python venv setup based on current directory name

Tags: linux, directory, alias, virtualenv, cwd

Can't seem to figure out what the issue is. This is on a Fedora 37 with default setup (bash, gnome, etc...).

What I want to achieve is to create an alias that creates a python virtual environment, where the folder name for the virtual environment is the name of the current working directory (something akin to `python3 -m venv $cwd`).
 This is helpful especially when activating the venv (and later switching directories between project) you can easily identify which venv is enabled.

But for some odd reason this is not working as I expected. To note that I don't have much experience in creating complex aliases but still. I have created the following vars in `.bashrc`:

- `export cwd="pwd | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev"`

  - If I run this in termnial it displays the directory name `test` as I need it, but when running `$cwd` in the terminal I get `home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test`
- `export cwd2="${PWD##*/}"`

  - This one just displays my username for some reason. I've searched here on stackoverflow and this was one of the suggested methods to get the current directory name

Some indication on how to get started or where to look for info are appreciated. I've tried to search on multiple sources but I can't seem to figure it. I read somewhere that double and single quotes make a difference, but I couldn't understand why and if it would affect this behaviour.

EDIT: To clarify, what I want my alias to run is i.e:

- `python3 -m venv <CURRENT_DIRECTORY_NAME> && source <CURRENT_DIRECTORY_NAME>/bin/activate && [ ! -f ./requirements.txt ] || pip install -r requirements.txt`

  - This creates a virtual for python projects
- `python3 -m venv <CURRENT_DIRECTORY_NAME> && source <CURRENT_DIRECTORY_NAME>/bin/activate && pip install nodeenv && nodeenv -p`

  - This creates virtual environments for projects that depend on nodejs, which in itself depend on python venv

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want, but if you want the the current working directory to hold the virtual environment, doesn't `python3 -m venv .` do the trick?

Comment: Well the point is not to only run that command, I have a batch of commands that I need to run to setup the dev environment that depends on python venvs.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I've edited my post with further clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is wrong with `$cwd`?

When you use `cwd="pwd | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev"` and then `$cwd` you are actually running `pwd` with arguments (you do not pipe the output). So basically you are running something like this:

```bash
pwd '|' rev '|' cut '-d' "'/'" '-f1' '|' rev
```

You do not see any error because `pwd` will ignore non-option arguments. If you use `/bin/pwd` instead of `pwd` built-in you can notice the message:

```
$> /bin/pwd '|'
#Output
/bin/pwd: ignoring non-option arguments
```

You can test that behavior with this simple `script.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

printf "I got: %s\n" "$@"
```

<sup>Make sure you set execution permissions to `script.sh`</sup>

Now change your `cwd` to:

```bash
cwd="./script.sh | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev"
```

And run `$cwd`:

```bash
(shell)> $cwd
#Output
I got: |
I got: rev
I got: |
I got: cut
I got: -d
I got: '/'
I got: -f1
I got: |
I got: rev
```

As you can see above the script `./script.sh` actually got the values becuase they were passed as arguments so they were not piped.

If you do want to pipe the content stored in the variable `$cwd` you will have to use `eval`, like this:

```bash
eval $cwd
#Output:
test
```

I recommend you use `functions` instead of using strings to run commands (you will avoid these kinds of problems):

```bash
getBaseName() { 
   pwd | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev 
}

getBaseName
#Output:
test
```

Btw, what you are trying to do (print only test) can be achieved by using the command `basename`:

```bash
basename $(pwd)

#Output:
test
```

**Regarding your commands** you want to create them an alias. Again, I suggest you use functions (in my opinion alias should be used for short/non-complex commands)

So you can create a function for your two scripts. Also I suggest you use `.` as a `<CURRENT_DIRECTORY_NAME>` since using a `.` will make reference to your current directory. If you pass the output of `$cwd` this will not make reference to your current path but a directory in your current path which might not exist.

What I meant above is that if you are places under this path:

```
home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test
```

And you use `$cwd` for passing the *current working directory* to the python venv like this: `python3 -m venv "$cwd"` what you are actually passing is this path `home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test/$cwd` where in your case `cwd` is `test` then the real path you are passing is: `home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test/test`.

#### Solution to your "alias"

```bash
createVenv() {
python3 -m venv . && source ./bin/activate && [ ! -f ./requirements.txt ] || pip install -r requirements.txt
}

createVenvNode(){
python3 -m venv . && source ./bin/activate && pip install nodeenv && nodeenv -p
}
```

Or since you really want to create a `venv` environment in a new folder (where its name should be the basename of your current directory) then the functions would be:

```bash
createVenv() {

# dest="${PWD##*/}"
# You can run the function `getBaseName` and assign its output like this:
dest=$(getBaseName)

if python3 -m venv "$dest" ; then
  cd "$dest"
  source "./bin/activate"
  [ ! -f "./requirements.txt" ] || pip install -r requirements.txt
  echo You are now in new venv environment
else
   echo "Failed to create 'venv' environment" >&2
fi

}

createVenvNode(){

# dest="${PWD##*/}"

# You can run the function `getBaseName` and assign its output like this:
dest=$(getBaseName)

if python3 -m venv "$dest" ; then
   cd "$dest"
   source "./bin/activate"
   # You can test the exit status of these commands with an if statement too
   pip install nodeenv && nodeenv -p
   echo You are now in new venv environment
else
   echo "Failed to create 'venv' environment" >&2
}
```

Comment: I had this previous setup with "python3 -m venv ." but the problem is that all venv files are dumped in the current folder, and that's not what I want. If I pass a directory name, then this directory will be used for the venv name and all venv related files are inside it. So something like "home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test/test" which is what I actually want, because otherwise all venv files are inside "home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test/" mixed with my other project folders.

Comment: Also from other posts, I noted that "basename" is often not used due to it being a 3rd party library and that the folder name could be fetched with regular tools. I don't really mind using it, but if there's a more "natural" of doing it (like I was attempting to) I would prefer that method.

Comment: @calexandru I've updated the answer (you have to use `cd $dest` in order to activate and install the dependencies of the new venv enviroment).  Regarding: `export cwd2="${PWD##*/}". "This one just displays my username for some reason"`, where are you running that command? Because If you run it in your home directory `/home/user` then that should be the reason why you get the username.

Comment: @calexandru Use the last two functions I provided, they should work, and wherever you are located it should create a venv with the same as the base-name of your PWD. Btw, if you run twice (or more) the one of the functions in the same directory what would happen is that it will probably update or add some missing dependencies (since the venv is already created it seems that when you create another one in the same location only update some contents/files, they are not removed)

Comment: `$cwd2"` I run this from within `home/<USERNAME>/Projects/VueJS/test` and my username is displayed, it's just something odd happening that I can't seem to comprehend what is the root cause for that.

Comment: @calexandru I have no idea what is wrong in your case, however instead of using "${PWD}" use your function, like this: `dest=$(getBaseName)` (I've updated the answer)

Comment: @calexandru Btw, if you run `echo ${PWD}` in different directories, what does it return?

Comment: So this is the odd part, it does the proper path, but if I run it via an alias I either get the base folder or my username, which is what confuses me most of the time of why this is happening.

Comment: @calexandru that should not happen, are you sure you are using alias? Because if you do this: `export cwd2="${PWD##*/}"` (assign a variable) that always will have the same value. Provide in your question more details about that.

Comment: I honestly don't have any more details to be honest. I used it as an alias and after running source .bashrc that would start happening. Though that would stop behaving like that after a restart. I'll try what you suggested this week and will comeback, thank you.

Comment: @calexandru sure, no problem! Hopefully we found solution.

Comment: Hey @Edgar so after re-reading your suggested solution, I concluded that that in your opinion you discourage from using aliases, as what I want to achieve is something a bit more complex. While I don't fully agree (and I don't have any solid counter arguments), I'll accept your solution. Appreciate the effort you put on this :+1:

Comment: @calexandru oh, many thanks! Actually aliases in my opinion are useful (and I often use them) however when the aliases to use are large commands the best option here is to use functions (or maybe a script)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do aliases ... try

```
alias cwd="pwd | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev"
```

What's happening with yours is they get evaluated ONCE, when bashrc gets sourced, and your username happens to be the name of your home directory, the last path element when your bashrc was sourced.

Comment: I know how to set an alias (and I forgot to add this), but even setting cwd to an alias it did not work for me. I was still getting the same results.